# Preservation of small limits implies preservation of all limits

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits

Let $\Phi:\mathscr B\to\mathscr A $ a functor between categories which preserves small limits (colimits).

There are non-trivial conditions on $\Phi $, $\mathscr A $ or $\mathscr B $ which makes true the implication
$$\Phi\,\text {preserves small limits (colimits)}\implies\Phi\,\text {preserves all limits  (colimits)?} $$

This question come from the fact that a small colimit (limit) can be seen as a universal (couniversal) arrow in suitable diagram categories, while this is not the case for large ones.

Comment: A right adjoint preserves whatever limits exist.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I better explained my question .

Comment: As Kevin Carlson says, if $\Phi$ is a right resp. left adjoint, it preserves whatever limits resp. colimits exist. So you can find conditions by looking at adjoint functor theorems: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/adjoint+functor+theorem